# Change prompt with echo to show current directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-formatting, echo

## Problem:

I was hoping this would be something simple to do. I currently have my script changing my directory among other things and I was hoping that I could make the script change the line using [echo](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html) to always display the current directory. A simple example of what I had in mind was (*Please note the directories being used are arbitrary and not actually true*):

## TL;DR;

I would just like to have a line at the top of my script that tells me the current directory. Then while the rest of the script is running and if the directory changes I would like that top line to change with it to always display the current directory

## **CODE:**

```
echo -e "Current Directory $PWD"
echo -en "\e[0K\r Finding folder"
cd /home/accounts
echo -en "\r\033[0K Inside folder"
cd /apps/foo/bar
echo -e "\e[0K\r Welcome to the app, enjoy!"
```

## **Expected Output:**

**At initial execution (Before the 1st cd command is executed)**

```
Line 1: Current Directory: /var/www/project
Line 2: Finding Folder
```

**After the 1st cd command is executed**

```
Line 1: Current Directory: /home/accounts
Line 2: Inside Folder
```

**After the 2nd cd command is executed**

```
Line 1: Current Directory: /apps/foo/bar
Line 2: Welcome to the app, enjoy!
```

Comment: What do you mean by instance? What do you have to do to get these outputs? What did you get? and how did you get it?

Comment: This question is unclear: I have no idea what you are trying to do. What you have done. or what you are struggling with.

Comment: The verbiage might be incorrect so I apologize. I shall edit it to make more sense but long story short I would like to have at the top of my output say "Current Directory : foo/bar" and while the script continues to execute whenever the directory changes I was hoping to update that line with the new directory @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: I as still confused. You have one script and it has the `cd` in it.

Comment: If you want to overwrite a line that got printed to the terminal, have a look at [Overwrite last line on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11283625).

Answer (score 1):

For setting the prompt you use the variable `PS1` not `echo`.
In `bash` you can also use `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

E.G.
using prompt codes

```
PS1='# \w '
```

or using commands

```
PS1="$(pwd)"
```

or variables

```
PS1="$PWD"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an alias in your script:

```
alias echo='printf "Current Directory: $PWD\n" && echo'
```

Note that if you add this line to your script it will not change `echo` outside of your script. If you want to get the regular behavior of echo you can slash escape it:

```
\echo This will not produce the Current Directory line
```